# How to capitalize each first word in a dot-separated string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a string:

```
https://san.dan.wan/pathway/conmtines
```

I am interested in this part:

```
san.dan.wan
```

and I want to convert it into:

```
San.Dan.Wan
```

so that each word is capitalized.

Comment: Is your input `https://san.dan.wan//pathway/conmtines
` or `san.dan.wan`?

Comment: `https://san.dan.wan/pathway/continues` < a string

Comment: I have edited your question in order to make your intent more clear. Please refer to the [how to ask pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you! ill keep it in mind

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following. Firstly you split the string on each `.`. following this you can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create a new array and capitalize each name. Then use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to turn it from an array to a string.

```js
let url = 'https://san.dan.wan//pathway/conmtines';
let urlStr = url.split('/')[2];
let newStr = urlStr.split('.').map(name => {
  return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
}).join('.')

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: While this code works, it may be helpful to point out what it is doing.

Comment: @k0pernikus just put the answer up first while then adding the explanation

Comment: Furthermore, how to split it from https://san.dan.wan//pathway/conmtines string? and not let urlStr = 'san.dan.wan'; ?

Comment: This answer may not include the parsing process from `https://san.dan.wan//pathway/conmtines`.

Comment: Please note that its `let url = 'https://san.dan.wan/pathway/conmtines';` and not `let url = 'https://san.dan.wan//pathway/conmtines';`

Comment: I think it'll be let urlStr = url.split('/')[2];